# Firestore Snapshot with Coroutines?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-livedata

Hello I tried to make Coroutines Flow (using callbackFlow) and tried to convert it to live data, but it seems it's not updating.

You can see my code below:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
suspend fun checkInDanger(): Flow<NetworkStatus<List<UserFire>>> = callbackFlow {
    val check = fs.collection(UserFire.COLLECTION).whereEqualTo(UserFire.DANGER, true)
        .addSnapshotListener { value, e ->
            if (e != null) {
                trySend(NetworkStatus.Failed("Error occurred\n${e.code}"))
                return@addSnapshotListener
            }
            if (value == null || value.isEmpty) trySend(NetworkStatus.Empty)
            else {
                val users = value.map { it.toObject(UserFire::class.java) }
                trySend(NetworkStatus.Success(users))
            }
        }
    awaitClose {  }
}.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
```

On my repositories:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
override suspend fun checkInDanger(): Flow<Status<List<User>>> = flow {
    when (val result = network.checkInDanger().first()) {
        is NetworkStatus.Success -> emit(Status.Success(result.data.map {
            MapVal.userFireToDom(it)
        }))
        is NetworkStatus.Empty -> emit(Status.Success(listOf<User>()))
        is NetworkStatus.Failed -> emit(Status.Error(null, result.error))
    }
}
```

In my ViewModel:

```
val checkInDanger = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
    try {
        useCase.checkInDanger().collectLatest {
            emit(it)
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

But when I changed the value in my Firebase, it's not fetching new data...
Anyone know why it's not fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of find the way, but it's with callback, if we used callback, it can fetch data update even without live-data, but for my case I tried to push the callback to live data again,
so the code will be like this:

```
fun checkInDanger(networkStatus: (NetworkStatus<List<UserFire>>) -> Unit) {
    fs.collection(UserFire.COLLECTION).whereEqualTo(UserFire.DANGER, true)
        .addSnapshotListener { value, e ->
            if (e != null) {
                networkStatus(NetworkStatus.Failed("Error occurred\n${e.code}"))
                return@addSnapshotListener
            }
            if (value == null || value.isEmpty) networkStatus(NetworkStatus.Empty)
            else {
                val users = value.map { it.toObject(UserFire::class.java) }
                networkStatus(NetworkStatus.Success(users))
            }
        }
}
```

In my repositories:

```
override fun checkInDanger(callback: (Status<List<User>>) -> Unit) {
    network.checkInDanger { result ->
        when (result) {
            is NetworkStatus.Success -> callback(Status.Success(result.data.map {
                MapVal.userFireToDom(it)
            }))
            is NetworkStatus.Empty -> callback(Status.Success(listOf<User>()))
            is NetworkStatus.Failed -> callback(Status.Error(null, result.error))
        }
    }
}
```

In my ViewModel:

```
fun checkInDanger(callback: (Status<List<User>>) -> Unit) = useCase.checkInDanger { callback(it) }

val setUsers = MutableLiveData<List<User>>().apply { this.value = listOf() }
val users: LiveData<List<User>> = setUsers
```

In my UI Class (Fragment Main):

```
val inDangerCallback: (Status<List<User>>) -> Unit =  {
    if (relative != null) {
        when (it) {
            is Status.Success ->
                viewModel.setUsers.value =
                    it.data?.filter { user -> user.username in relative!!.pure }
            else -> requireView().createSnackBar(it.error!!, 1000)
        }
    }
}
viewModel.checkInDanger(inDangerCallback)

viewModel.users.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { users ->
    println(users.size})
    users?.forEach { user -> println(user.username) }
}
```

And the code can run perfectly and update automatically...